# instagram api. How to use users data if they are not in my sandbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram, instagram-api

I use instagram api in my app. And I want to search pictures and display they by location. But it is impossible because of instagram API update. Do you know any ways to decide this problem

Answer (score 0):

Without being approved you are not able to let user's authorize their Instagram account with your app and get the auth token. A work around could be that instead asking a user to login in with Instagram
- you can ask them to enter their instgram handle
- use the api todo a search of that and get their instagram id
- if their profile is public you can use the users/user-id/media/recent instagram api endpoint to get the content
- once you have the media ids of their posted images you can get the location.